# Wagtail PASSWORD_REQUIRED_TEMPLATE is not overriding the default login

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm building a global login page for Wagtail. The setting for PASSWORD_REQUIRED_TEMPLATE isn't working. In fact, i can't find n example where it actually does work which makes me think that I don't understand what it's supposed to do.

When I add; `PASSWORD_REQUIRED_TEMPLATE = 'utils/auth/password-required.html'` to the settings file it does not catch the login form and use my custom form.

Is this a know issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood what this is for. The `PASSWORD_REQUIRED_TEMPLATE` is used when someone tries to access a page that has been [marked as private](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/advanced_topics/settings.html#private-pages-documents), and requires a password to view.

This is independent of whether or not the user is logged in, and is a different form entirely from the regular login form, which appears to be what you're trying to override.

If you want to change the *frontend* login form, then you need to set [`WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_TEMPLATE`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/advanced_topics/privacy.html#setting-up-a-login-page).

If you want to change the *admin* login form you need to override the [`wagtailadmin/login.html` template](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html#extending-the-login-form).